# how to unzip, crop, stack and save GTiff rasters using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, stack, iteration, raster

I have several zip files, each containing meteorological data for a decade, from 1960 to 2010 (5 zip files).
I need to unzip them, crop or mask (whatever is the best option) each raster using the shapefile of my study area (using it as a mask or according to its extent), then group the cropped tiff files using the stack function (unless there is a better function), calculate the average of each stack object (that should include the data per decade) and save each cropped average raster in a specific directory.
The most important: since I have 50 years of data I need to use a loop (or some iteration code).

Comment: Then, what's the issue? `for` doesn't work on your R instance? Please check `?for()` and `?list.files()` functions. The procedure you described in your post, just a matter of implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.